# How does redeployment of component with EJB beans on Java EE server work

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, application-server, hotdeploy, redeploy

Let's assume I have two deployment units and first one uses EJB bean of second one deployed and being used. I redeploy second one.

How does it work? Is redeployment different from just undeploy and deploy? Does redeployment prevent an errors until redeployment ends? Is it server specific or is it defined by Java EE?

Edit:
By redeployment I meant hot deployment. In particular I'm interested how is it handled regarding beans. It seems to be vendor specif. Here http://otndnld.oracle.co.jp/document/products/as10g/101300/B25221_03/web.1013/b13593/deploy006.htm documentation says that it's programer responsibility to take care.

Comment: Generally speaking, the main difference is that a deploy is a kind of wizard that let you configure the deployment. A redeploy will instead use previous configured parameters. Then it depends, a redeploy can be either undeploy+deploy or an hot deploy. In the latter case you deploy will the app is running, is convenient especially during development, but will soon lead to memory problem.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo, your comment helped me to clarify what I was thinking about - it's hot deploy. I'm wondering whether is a safe or not.